# Are Preprocessor Directives Indentation Sensitive in F#?

Tags: f#

FSI version: 11.0.50727.1

So I was working on an F# shell script and I ran across something that sort of surprised me.

When I did this:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
    #r "System.Data.dll"
    #r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
    #r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
#endif

open System
```

I got an FS0010 error when I pasted the block into the FSI.  But if I did not indent the `#r` lines, no FS0010 error.  I'm just sort of surprised that preprocessor lines would be indentation sensitive. Is this a compiler issue or is there something else at work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the specification and documentation are quite unclear on this topic, but the specification makes a notable distinction between *lexical preprocessor directives* and *compiler directives* (see [§12.4](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819004%C2%A8)):

> *Compiler directives* are declarations in non-nested modules or namespace declaration groups in the following form:
>
> ```
> # id string ... string
> ```
>
> The *lexical preprocessor directives* `#if`, `#else`, `#endif` and `#indent "off"` are similar to compiler directives. For details on `#if`, `#else`, `#endif`, see §3.3. The `#indent "off"` directive is described in §18.4.

My interpretation is that *lexical preprocessor directives* are actually hanled by some pre-processor before running the main compilation and so the indentation does not matter for these.

On the other hand, directives like `#r`, `#load`, `#time` etc. are processed later by the compiler and so they need to match the usual F# indentation guidelines.

As @unwind says, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx) states "Indentation is not significant for preprocessor directives", but I think this applies only to the preprocessor directives listed on that documentation page (which are *lexical preprocessor directives* and not *compiler directives*).

Comment: Thanks Tomas. It was easy enough to work around once I figured it out.  I just wondered if it were a genuine problem or simply me misunderstanding something.

Comment: It is an interesting point :-) I was quite curious if this is actually properly described somewhere - the specification helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx), it must be something else at work:

> Indentation is not significant for preprocessor directives.

Comment: You know it's funny unwind--I looked at the doc page you linked but I missed that part about indentation.  That's what I get for skimming docs.